# Check Update permissions on object instance/record

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

We can use Schema.sObjectType.Contact.isUpdatable() to check if the current user has permissions to update Contact objects in general.

I want this for dynamic object.my object name is within the objName string variable.

Answer (score 1):

String objName = 'Account';
Boolean isUpdateableAccount = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().isUpdateable();